# Xml Java adapter not working properly

Tags: java, jaxb, xmladapter

Require help: following XmlJavaTypeAdapter type is not working properly:

```
public class TestAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, Object> {

 public Object marshal(Object arg0) throws Exception {
  System.out.println("Test Adapter");
  return null;
 }

 public Object unmarshal(Object arg0) throws Exception {
  System.out.println("Test Adapter");
  return null;
 }
}
```

I am using the "TestAdapter" like :

```
'@XmlRootElement
 @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = TestAdapter.class)
 public TestClass{...}'
```

But the problem I am facing is the "TestAdapter" is never getting invoked.

Comment: Please be more specific on what is actual issue here. Paste some more code or error or describe what is problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XmlAdapter does not apply on root elements.

And i don't think there's an implementation of JAXB that is able to do it.

See : [Using an adapter to marshal a class to a root element with MOXy or any other JAXB implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640566/using-an-adapter-to-marshal-a-class-to-a-root-element-with-moxy-or-any-other-jax)

As said in the linked topic, you can apply your adapter logic manually to workaround your problem.